# Multiple strings search with replace to regenerate a .config file

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I am trying to regenerate the .config file of a buildroot system from a working system running on an OS produced from the buildroot system, i.e. OpenWRT. For instance, I have a Seagate GoFLEX Home unit running on a self-built OpenWRT OS that I have already lost its original .config file. Sure and I can regenerate the .config file by running a *make menuconfig* and start selecting all packages. But, this process is very tedious. So, I came up with the following process to regenerate the .config file.

1. Log into my Seagate GoFLEX Home unit and perform *opkg list-installed | awk '{print $1}' > /tmp/opkg-list-installed.txt* to generate a list of installed package to show me what packages have been installed.

   The excerpt of *opkg list-installed* dump before processed by *awk* looks like this:

   ```
   ac-power-control-by-USB-hub - 0.0.1-1
   ahcpd - 0.53-2
   alsa-lib - 1.0.28-1
   alsa-lib-dev - 1.0.28-1
   ...
   ```

   After processed by *awk* looks like this:

   ```
   ac-power-control-by-USB-hub
   ahcpd
   alsa-lib
   alsa-lib-dev
   ...
   ```

   And, the sample of .config file looks like this:

   ```
   # CONFIG_PACKAGE_ac-power-control-by-USB-hub is not set
   # CONFIG_PACKAGE_ahcpd is not set
   # CONFIG_PACKAGE_alsa-lib is not set
   # CONFIG_PACKAGE_alsa-lib-dev is not set
   # CONFIG_PACKAGE_amrnb is not set
   ...
   ```
2. Transfer the */tmp/opkg-list-installed.txt* to my host computer where the buildroot system is.
3. Use *sed* to process the generated list file (*/tmp/opkg-list-installed.txt*) to freshen up the .config file as shown below.

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   LIST="/tmp/opkg-list-installed.txt"
   FCFG="/tmp/.config"

   echo -n "Processing "

   for f in $(cat $LIST)
   do
       echo -n "."
       sed -i "s|# CONFIG_PACKAGE_$f is not set|CONFIG_PACKAGE_$f=y|g" $FCFG
   done

   echo
   echo "done"
   ```
4. Because some packages contain sub-packages and/or sub-modules, this process isn't complete until after running a *make menuconfig* to re-freshen up (regenerate) the .config file.

   The following is what I want the above excerpt .config file to look like:

   ```
   CONFIG_PACKAGE_ac-power-control-by-USB-hub=y
   CONFIG_PACKAGE_ahcpd=y
   CONFIG_PACKAGE_alsa-lib=y
   CONFIG_PACKAGE_alsa-lib-dev=y
   # CONFIG_PACKAGE_amrnb is not set
   ...
   ```

In the step #3 above, it takes about 100 seconds for my AMD64 computer to regenerate the .config file. To me, this process is a bit slow and am wondering if anyone out here knows of a better way to regenerate the .config file from a list of installed packages.

**EDIT**: I updated the above with some sample data.

Comment: What does the `$LIST` look like? Could you post a sample?

Comment: Sorry about the missing data. I have edited the original post to include some sample data.

Answer (score 3):

The use of a `for` loop with `cat` is an anti-pattern in the shell. You should use a `while read` loop instead. However, it looks like the main reason your code is slow is that you're calling `sed` and running through the entire file `$FCFG` once for every word of `$LIST`. I would suggest a different approach entirely, using `awk` instead of your loop:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}{for(i in a)sub("# CONFIG_PACKAGE_" i " is not set", "CONFIG_PACKAGE_" i "=y")}1' "$LIST" "$FCFG"
```

The first block reads `$LIST` into memory and the second block performs the same substitutions that you were using `sed` to do.

I am assuming that your file `$LIST` consists of a single word on each line.

To perform your edits "in-place", you can use

```
awk '...' "$LIST" "$FCFG" > tmp && mv tmp "$FCFG"
```

With a slight modification (changing `$0` to `$1` in the first block), you can skip a step and go from your original input files to the desired output:

```
$ cat list
ac-power-control-by-USB-hub - 0.0.1-1
ahcpd - 0.53-2
alsa-lib - 1.0.28-1
alsa-lib-dev - 1.0.28-1
$ cat config
# CONFIG_PACKAGE_ac-power-control-by-USB-hub is not set
# CONFIG_PACKAGE_ahcpd is not set
# CONFIG_PACKAGE_alsa-lib is not set
# CONFIG_PACKAGE_alsa-lib-dev is not set
# CONFIG_PACKAGE_amrnb is not set
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}{for(i in a)sub("# CONFIG_PACKAGE_" i " is not set", "CONFIG_PACKAGE_" i "=y")}1' list config
CONFIG_PACKAGE_ac-power-control-by-USB-hub=y
CONFIG_PACKAGE_ahcpd=y
CONFIG_PACKAGE_alsa-lib=y
CONFIG_PACKAGE_alsa-lib-dev=y
# CONFIG_PACKAGE_amrnb is not set
```

Comment: I am not that familiar with awk, but it doesn't seem to work. I really don't know what happens, but it looks like the script never touches both the *opkg-list-installed.txt* and the *.config* files (both time stamp and size remain the same for both files). I even tried to replace *i* with *$i* and ended with the same problem, unfortunately.

Comment: There was a missing `{print}` block, meaning that nothing would be printed. I've added a `1` to the end of the one-liner, which is a common shorthand for `{print}`. It should print to standard output now, then you can use the redirection in the second code block to overwrite your original file if you're happy with the output.

Comment: @user3767809 I've added a demo which shows you how to go from the original list to the desired output

Comment: That does the trick and now it works. If you noticed from my original post, I use *opkg list-installed | awk '{print $1}' > /tmp/opkg-list-installed.txt* to generate the list. Since I am not very familiar with *awk*, do you think you can help me to combine this with your one liner *awk* into a single liner code?

Comment: @user3767809 that's what the last example does, as it uses `$1` to save the first field in the array `a`.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you meant. I am looking for help to combine this *opkg list-installed | awk '{print $1}' > list* with your one liner script (*awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}{for(i in a)sub("# CONFIG_PACKAGE_" i " is not set", "CONFIG_PACKAGE_" i "=y")}1' list config*) into a single liner script to avoid intermediate *list* file to even speed up the process.

Comment: @user3767809 with bash you can use `awk '...' <(opkg ...) "$FCFG"`, or on other shells you can do `opkg ... | awk '...' - "$FCFG"`. Use one of those with the second example that uses only the first field, `$1`.

Comment: Per your suggestion and if I understand it correctly, I used this script (*ssh root@10.0.0.10 "opkg list-installed" | awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}{for(i in a)sub("# CONFIG_PACKAGE_" i " is not set", "CONFIG_PACKAGE_" i "=y")}1' - .config > .config.new*) to remotely retrieve the the list of installed packages and let the awk scripts to process the data. It looks like this method works. However, it takes about 225 seconds to complete which is about 125 seconds longer than my slow scripts. I must have done something wrong.

Comment: @user3767809 I'm surprised by that - unfortunately I'm not sure why it'd be the case. It would be useful to identify which part of the process is taking so long - is it the `opkg` or the `awk`?

Comment: Whether I separate the opkg and awk, the process takes about the same amount of time to finish. So, it looks like the problem is within awk. Like I said before, I am not good with awk. So, I have no idea with the scripts from my concoction. I tried to remove the loop (for(i in a)) and the process produces 0 size file.

Answer (score 0):

Sed works on a "program" which can be multiple lines.
Assemble the edits into a file:

```
for f in $(</tmp/opkg-list-installed.txt)
do echo "s@# ... $f@...$f=y@g" ; done > /tmp/edits
sed -i -f /tmp/edits $FCFG
```